# $scope variable inside the function is not getting updated in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
<button class="button button-primary"
        ng-click="editSchedule(controlCenter.selected)">
  Edit Schedule
</button>
```

From Button i am calling the function

```
$scope.records = [];

$scope.editSchedule = function(data) {
    var s = "/api/v1/controlcenter/sitegroups?";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
        s += "ids=" + data[i]._id + "&";
    }
    s += "ids=" + data[data.length - 1]._id;

    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url:s,
    }).then(
        function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.records = response.data;
            console.log("angular api call");
            console.log($scope.records);
        },
        function errorCallback(response) {
            alert("Error. Try Again!");
        }
    );
};
```

I am getting Api response but it is not being updated in $scope.records variable .

Comment: What is the console output?

Comment: can you log your response in the console and see what is being sent back to you ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your view is in the same scope as `$scope.records`, it must be something very silly! Seems like your controller and your view are not the same.